# Typescript Error Ionic 2

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Seguinte Erro:

> Type 'typeof LoginPage' is not assignable to type 'typeof HomePage'.

Código:

```
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

if(user) {
  this.rootPage = HomePage;
} else {
  this.rootPage = LoginPage; // Erro nessa linha
}
```

Comment: Qual o tipo de `this.rootPage` e quais classes `HomePage` e `LoginPage` extendem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só arrumar a declaração da variável:

```
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

let rootPage:Any;

if(user) {
  this.rootPage = HomePage;
} else {
  this.rootPage = LoginPage; // Erro nessa linha
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare:

`rootPage: any;`

Confirme qual é o tipo de dado do atributo `rootPage`. Como nesse caso você somente saberá qual será o componente em tempo de execução é preciso deixar passar em tempo de compilação.

TypeScript Docs - Any: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any

Esse é um projeto bastante interessante para usar como exemplo de código: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app